# page refreshing regarding

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, struts2, myeclipse

i have MyEclipse 8.0, i am making a application based on Struts 2 and hibernate.

code changes are not reflect in JSP when i refresher the page on firefox.
i have tried on firefox, chrome, and internet explorer it show previous UI of jsp not the updated UI.
i have clear everything on browsers and i have also deployed the application many times but problem persist.

when i use my eclipse browser for this, eclipse are crash.
then restart the system and  again open the My eclipse.
each time when i refresh the page on my eclipse browser, my eclipse crash.
i have reinstalled My Eclipse also.

please suggest.

Comment: have you checked if your jsp in the newly deployed application has the required changes? if so, you're not accessing the jsp properly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look for any problems in your Project's build path. Chances are, your changes aren't getting re-deployed due to a build path error.

Comment: +1 this problem is not with Struts2 or hibernate,its related to application context is not being redepolyed properly